# Spresenseで高解像度RBG画像データを取得する方法

Tags: spresense

SpresenseでSpresenseカメラから1枚の高解像度RBG画像データを取得し、その後に画像処理を行うことが目的です。
「Spresense Arduino Library 開発ガイド」にて
3.2. Camera ライブラリ
第一、第二引数で画像の縦横サイズを指定します。第三引数で画像のピクセルフォーマットを指定します。
現在、画像のピクセルフォーマットはJPEGのみサポートしています。

3.2.6. 取得した画像を変換する。
convertPixformat()は、YUV422からRGB、YUV422からGLAY、の2つのみ対応しています。

つまり、Arduino Libraryでは高解像度RBG画像データは取得できない、と理解しました。
Spresense SDKを使うとできるのでしょうか？ サンプルコード参照場所を知りたいです。

Comment: 資料的にはこの辺を読み解けば良いのでは？ [5.4. Camera](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html#_camera), [5.4.5. imageサイズとframe rateの制約](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html#_image%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E3%81%A8frame_rate%E3%81%AE%E5%88%B6%E7%B4%84), [spresense/examples/camera/](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/tree/master/examples/camera/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spresense SDKでcameraのサンプルはexamples/cameraにありますが、
このサンプルだと、STILL_CAMTURE場合の設定はJPEGになってますね。
5５１行目あたりのcamera_prepare()というスタティック関数でフォーマットを指定しているので、これをV4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB565に変更すれば行けるかもしれません。
ただ、そもそもメモリが足りなそうです。　フルHDでさえ1920*1080*2(Byte)=約4MByteなので、Spresenseのメモリサイズ1.5MByteを超えてます。

やりようとしては、
JPEGデコードのライブラリ（libjpegのようです)とサンプル：examples/jpeg_decodeがあるので、
JPEGで高精細で取って、保存しつつ、libjpegでライン毎にデコードして表示したり加工したりする、
というところでしょうか。

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html#_jpeg_decoder

参考になれば幸いです。